# What does "led by" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "organized by Redpoint Ventures" or "Redpoint Ventures invested the most money in this startup"?

> The company recently wrapped up a $3.5 million seed round **led by Redpoint Ventures** and joined by Kimbal Musk, Figma CEO Dylan Field, AngelList cofounder Naval Ravikant, The Chainsmokers, Tinder cofounder Sean Rad, and others.

Source: https://www.businessinsider.com/ceo-founder-profitboss-landed-seed-round-investment-2020-10

Comment: _Redpoint ventures are in the forefront of the investments_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the second option.

In the context of startups trying to raise rounds of funding from venture capital firms, startups need to secure commitments from venture capital firms. Typically, one venture capital firm **leads** the funding round by literally committing the most money.

*Led by* is an extremely common phrasal verb that accompanies this kind of event.

It's the startup receiving the funding that usually *organizes* the funding round.

You can see there are plenty of [news results in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22led%20by%22%20funding%20venture).